# How can I show success message (not alert box) in home page after successful signup

Tags: codeigniter

How can I show a success message (not alert box) in home page after a successful signup?

This is my controller function.

```
public function reg()
    {
        $data['baseurl'] = base_url();
        $baseurl    =   base_url();
        $this->load->model('Regdatabase');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[cpassword]|md5');
        $userdata['id']    =    Null; 
        $userdata['firstname']   =  $this->input->post('firstname');
        $userdata['lastname']   =   $this->input->post('lastname');
        $userdata['email']  =   $this->input->post('email');
        $userdata['password']   =   $this->input->post('password');
        $userdata['status']     =   "1";
        $this->Regdatabase->DataInsert($userdata);
        // INSERT DATA INTO TABLE
        redirect($baseurl.'register');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set your success message in session flash message and then show in home page as you want.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'success');
```

to get success message

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('success_msg');
```

Set flash message in your controller, then redirect to home page after successfull registration.

Answer (score 1):

1. On view page set form "action" to same page(controller/function).
2. So now when user click submit, the same page will load again.
3. Now ensure that is user clicked submit.
4. If yes, get all inputs and save it to DB.
5. Now set $data['msg']='1'.
6. Now load view page with data.
7. In view page set message according to $msg.

See below example to get clear idea..

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); // Load validation library.
    $this->load->model('register_model');
    $data['msg']=NULL; // Declare msg as NULL.

    // On form submit.
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
        // Input fields validations
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|max_length[100]|min_length[3]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
        {
            $name=$this->input->post('name');

            $values=array('name' => $name);

            $result=$this->register_model->my_insert($values,'users');  // Insert user into database.

            if($result_id)
                $data['msg']='1';
            else
                $data['msg']='2';
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('register', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

flash data used to showing success messages in codeigniter

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');

You can also pass an array to set_flashdata(), in the same manner as set_userdata().

To read a flashdata variable:

$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Use parameter to redirect to home page with the success message.

   `redirect($baseurl.'home/index/success');`
2. Get parameter on home and show message according to that.

   `$msg=$this->uri->segment(3);`